# Inline assembly equivalent of .data MASM directive

Tags: assembly, d, inline-assembly, masm

I am curious as to what the equivalent of (for example)

```
        .data
x       dword 42
        .code
main    proc
        ; Do stuff here.
        ret
main    endp
        end
```

would be, if I were writing inline assembly (in D).  I understand I could do something like

```
int main()
{
    int x = 42;
    asm
    {
        // Do stuff here.
    }

    return 0;
}
```

, but the point of the exercise is not to 'cheat' by using D itself.

Comment: Actually, in the code you put up above that you considered cheating, the memory for `x` isn't allocated in the data section. It's allocated on the stack.

Comment: I doubt you can allocate memory in the data section using inline assembly. But if you were to create a global variable, that variable's memory would be allocated in the data section.

Comment: `const int x = 42;` or `static int x = 42;` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

D's inline assembler does not have the ability to set which section the code or data will be emitted to. It will always go into the same section as the code for the function it is embedded in.

But you can insert data into D's data segment using ordinary D declarations:

```
__gshared int x = 42;
```

Note that if you don't use __gshared, x will wind up in the thread local storage blocks, and will require specially generated code to access. Also, if the code is compiled with -fPIC, specially generated code will be required to access all data segment data.